# Pass parameter from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a next code in my view:

```
<% @todos.each do |todo| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= todo.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Create action', new_simple_action_path } %></td>
```

I want to pass todo.description to SimpleAction-controller.  I can rewrite my code like this and it will be work:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Create action', { :controller => 'simple_actions', :action => 'new', :todo => todo.description } %></td>
```

But I'm just wondering if is it possible to pass variable as parameter using new_simple_action_path ?

Comment: why exactly todo.description ? new_simple_action_path(todo) ?

Comment: It is a string, but I'm searching general solution. I can not change num of params in the new-method and looking for solution using params-hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
link_to 'Create action', new_simple_action_path(:todo => todo.description)
```